# Silverlight animations tool

Tags: silverlight

What is the best application to create Silverlight Animations, just as I would with Macromedia Flash to create Flash clips? Can I use those animations later as a part of a movie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official Microsoft tool to create animations in xaml is the Microsoft Expression Blend. You can download a trial [here](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/Blend_Overview.aspx).